# Removing a specific cell from a Collection View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to remove the first collection view cell. I'm having trouble getting the indexPath for the first item in the collection view. Here is what I've got so far.

```
-(void)removeFirstItemFromCollectionView
{
    NSLog(@"%i", [self.hostQueue count]);
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

        NSIndexPath * firstIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:(CollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView viewWithTag:0]];
        NSArray *indexPaths = @[firstIndexPath];

        //delete item from hostQueue
        [self.hostQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        // Now delete the items from the collection view.
        [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

I'm getting a crash with:

```
NSIndexPath * firstIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:(CollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView viewWithTag:0]];
```

In my dataSource I set the cell's tag equal to the indexPath.row. I guess this doesn't work? How should I be getting the first indexPath?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `indexPathForCell` as you know that you want to delete the first cell - index 0.  You can use the `NSIndexPath` class method `indexPathForItem:inSection:` to create the index path directly -

```
- (void)removeFirstItemFromCollectionView
{
    NSLog(@"%i", [self.hostQueue count]);
    //delete item from hostQueue
    [self.hostQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    // Now delete the items from the collection view.
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]];
```

}